# Faster return_inverse in np.unique

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large numpy 1D array with over a 100 million elements and am applying `np.unique` to it

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0,10000, size=100_000_000)

_, index = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
```

What I actually need is the `index` that is returned from `np.unique` but I do **not** need the unique array at all (i.e., it is throwaway). Since, in my real use case, I need to call `np.unique` many times on different arrays (all with the same length), this becomes the bottleneck. I'm guessing that a lot of the time is spent on sorting the unique array.

What is the a fastest way to obtain the `index` for a large 1D array (it may be over a billion elements in length)?

Is there a parallelized option?

Comment: Do you need it in sorted order? i.e. for an input : `[4, 0, 3, 3, 3]`, `index` would be `[2, 0, 1, 1, 1]`. Would an output like `[0, 1, 2, 2, 2]` work i.e. assign IDs as it runs along the length?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it does need to be in sorted order.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to parallelize this using multiprocessing

Comment: Would those always be positive integers in `x`?

Comment: Yes, the input array could be constrained (or simply shifted) to only have positive integers. I am super curious as to why this would help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `array-assignment` + `masking` + `indexing` trickery specific to the case of positive integers only in the input array `x` -

```
def return_inverse_only(x, maxnum=None):
    if maxnum is None:
        maxnum = x.max()+1 # Determines extent of indexing array
    p = np.zeros(maxnum, dtype=bool)
    p[x] = 1

    p2 = np.empty(maxnum, dtype=np.uint64)
    c = p.sum()
    p2[p] = np.arange(c)    
    out = p2[x]
    return out
```

If max number in the input array is known before-hahnd, feed in one-added number as `maxnum` to boost perf. further.

Timings on large arrays -

```
In [146]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: x = np.random.randint(0,10000, size=100000)

In [147]: %timeit np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
     ...: %timeit return_inverse_only(x)
     ...: %timeit return_inverse_only(x, maxnum=10000)
10.9 ms ± 229 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
539 µs ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
446 µs ± 30 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [148]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: x = np.random.randint(0,10000, size=1000000)

In [149]: %timeit np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
     ...: %timeit return_inverse_only(x)
     ...: %timeit return_inverse_only(x, maxnum=10000)
149 ms ± 5.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
6.1 ms ± 106 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.3 ms ± 504 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [150]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: x = np.random.randint(0,10000, size=10000000)

In [151]: %timeit np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
     ...: %timeit return_inverse_only(x)
     ...: %timeit return_inverse_only(x, maxnum=10000)
1.88 s ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
67.9 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
55.8 ms ± 1.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`30x+` speedup!

Comment: Thank you. I tested out the code and it is certainly faster. However, in my case, while the length of the array may be a billion elements in length, the `maxnum` can actually be much larger (e.g., 39959978131 is one example of `maxnum` and it can keep on growing). Since `p` and `p2` are of the same size as `maxnum`, most of my time is spent on creating these arrays (and I'm guessing that I'm swapping to disk). The answer that is returned is correct and the same as `np.unique(return_inverse=True)` but `np.unique` doesn't seem to have the same memory problems as your proposed solution.

Comment: Is there a reasonable compromise where we can be 10x faster but be as memory efficient as `np.unique`?

Comment: Additionally, I'm not entirely sure why this is happening but if I do `out = return_inverse_only(x)` followed by `out = return_inverse_only(out)` then I get a `'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` error. It looks like `maxnum = x.max()+1` is returning a floating point number instead of an int. The first call to `return_inverse_only` produces an `out` that has `dtype('uint64')` so, in theory, it should work as expected.

Comment: @slaw Are you facing memory error or just slowdown because of that memory requirement? If it's memory error, at which step is it happening?

Comment: I have 16GB RAM (Mac OSX) and, while I don't encounter a memory error (I kill the job before it completely locks up my computer), I see the memory consumption (displayed in Activity Monitor) rise up to over 40GB+ (I suspect that it is swapping with disk). This huge increase in memory happens in the `c = p.sum()` step.

Comment: I'm wondering if a scipy.sparse matrix could solve the problem here. It looks like `p.sum` necessarily turns `p` into a full in memory array

Comment: @slaw Doesn't seem like we can do better. Increase your system memory or wait for the future when you can.